# libGDX: How can I detect Scrollpane is scrolled at max Y?

Tags: java, libgdx, scrollpane

I need to add new items in the list when the player scroll at the end. So, how can I detect the `Scrollpane` reached to the end or maximum `Y`?

```
private Table list;
private ScrollPane scrollPane;

private void buildPlayersList() {
    list = new Table();
    scrollPane = new ScrollPane(list);
}

private boolean isTheEnd() {
    // condition !!!
    return scrollPane.getScrollY() >= scrollPane.getMaxY();
}

@Override
public void onTheEndRequest() {
    int offset = list.getRows();
    int limit = 10;

    Actor player = this.getPlayer(offset, limit);

    list.add(player).row();
}

private Actor getPlayer(int offset, int limit) {
    // retrieve player from database
    // ......
    Player player = database.getPlayer();

    Label label = new Label(player.getName(), style);
    return label;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456468/how-to-get-scrollpane-max-vvalue), you can use a ChangeListener looking for a change to getScrollY to execute the comparison of ScrollY & MaxY.

```
s1.vvalueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
                        Number old_val, Number new_val) {
        // if ScrollY == maxY; then displayMoreItems
        System.out.println(new_val.intValue());
    }
});
```

Comment: Or the `act()` method, depending on use case.